# JS object default single quote behavior

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have an empty object
`var obj = {}`
 where I want to add an element such as `obj[data] = "value";`

Lets say data is holding the value of 3001.

This will result in `obj = {'3001' : "value")`

The problem is, the key is by default in single quotes which is not applicable to be used in a .json file.

Assuming I cannot simply do `obj["3001"] = "value"` because data is parsed from a .csv file, how can i change the default behavior of objects to add a key in surrounded by double quotes?

Comment: the double/single quote is just a visual appearance of a string. by taking `JSON.stringify`, you get an ECMA-404 compliant [JSON](http://json.org/) string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to turn your js in JSON you can use the JSON.stringify method, and JSON.parse to do the reverse operation.

Example:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({'3001' : "value"}));
-> {"3001":"value"}
console.log(typeof JSON.stringify({'3001' : "value"}));
-> string
```